# Python: kubernetes exec failing with upgrade required message

Tags: python, python-2.7, kubernetes

**Scenario:**

I'm trying to run a basic `ls` command using `kubernetes` package via `cli.connect_post_namespaced_pod_exec()` however I get a stacktrace that I do not know how to debug. Yes I have tried searching around but I'm not really sure what the problem is as I'm using documentation example from [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/client-python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CoreV1Api.md#connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec)

**OS:**

macOS Sierra 10.12.2

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7

import logging

from pprint import pprint
from kubernetes import client, config

FORMAT = "[%(filename)s:%(lineno)s - %(funcName)s() ] %(message)s"
level = logging.DEBUG
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, level=level)

def main():
    path_to_config = "/Users/acabrer/.kube/config"
    config.load_kube_config(config_file=path_to_config)
    ns = "default"
    pod = "nginx"
    cmd = "ls"
    cli = cli = client.CoreV1Api()
    response = cli.connect_post_namespaced_pod_exec(pod, ns, stderr=True, stdin=True, stdout=True, command=cmd)
    pprint(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/acabrer/kube.py", line 16, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/acabrer/kube.py", line 12, in main
    response = cli.connect_post_namespaced_pod_exec(pod, ns, stderr=True, stdin=True, stdout=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/apis/core_v1_api.py", line 3605, in connect_post_namespaced_pod_exec
    (data) = self.connect_post_namespaced_pod_exec_with_http_info(name, namespace, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/apis/core_v1_api.py", line 3715, in connect_post_namespaced_pod_exec_with_http_info
    collection_formats=collection_formats)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 328, in call_api
    _return_http_data_only, collection_formats, _preload_content, _request_timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 152, in __call_api
    _request_timeout=_request_timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 373, in request
    body=body)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py", line 257, in POST
    body=body)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py", line 213, in request
    raise ApiException(http_resp=r)
kubernetes.client.rest.ApiException: (400)
Reason: Bad Request
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Date': 'Sat, 21 Jan 2017 00:55:28 GMT', 'Content-Length': '139', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Upgrade request required","reason":"BadRequest","code":400}
```

Any input would be much appreaciated.

**Edit 1:**

```
abrahams-mbp:.kube acabrer$ curl --help |grep TLSv
 -1, --tlsv1         Use >= TLSv1 (SSL)
     --tlsv1.0       Use TLSv1.0 (SSL)
     --tlsv1.1       Use TLSv1.1 (SSL)
     --tlsv1.2       Use TLSv1.2 (SSL)
abrahams-mbp:.kube acabrer$ python2.7 -c "import ssl; print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION_INFO"
(1, 0, 2, 10, 15)
```

**Edit 2:**

```
abrahams-mbp:.kube acabrer$ curl --tlsv1.2 https://x.x.x.x -k
Unauthorized
abrahams-mbp:.kube acabrer$ curl --tlsv1.1 https://x.x.x.x -k
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to x.x.x.x:-9836
```

**Edit 3:**
I put some print statements to see the full on request information in [api_client.py](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/client-python/blob/master/kubernetes/client/api_client.py#L341) and this is what I see.

**Note:** I removed the ip-address to my endpoint for security.

```
bash-3.2# vim /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py
bash-3.2# /Users/acabrer/kube.py
################
POST
https://x.x.x.x/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/nginx/exec
[('stdin', True), ('command', 'ls'), ('stderr', True), ('stdout', True)]
{'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'Swagger-Codegen/1.0.0-alpha/python'}
[]
None
################
```

Thanks,

-Abe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question here, this is a bug in actual python binding referenced here: https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/client-python/issues/58

Comment: Do you happen to know what the URL endpoint is that the client was using under the covers?

Comment: Let me see if I can hack a bit the client to print it.

Comment: Edited my OP, to include the info. I'm going to try doing a very small websocket implementation to see if it works.

Comment: I'm going to put this on the back burner and focus on kubernetes e2e testing using go instead.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered with the same problem.The solution to this is using kubernetes.stream .You need to import the package and change just one line code of code as follows:

```
from kubernetes.stream import stream
#response = cli.connect_post_namespaced_pod_exec(pod, ns, stderr=True, stdin=True,stdout=True, command=cmd)
response = stream(cli.connect_post_namespaced_pod_exec,pod, ns, stderr=True,stdin=True, stdout=True, command=cmd)
```

Comment: This was solved a while back already in the python kubernetes client. I had worked with a few of maintainers to test it out but unfortunately because of other issues outside of my control I had to ditch the python module.

Answer (score 0):

Python kuberenetes client now has a complete example how to do `exec`:

https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/exec.py

Answer (score -1):

Kubernetes 1.4+ REST API likely will not work with a Python client on MacOS X if you are using system Python 2.7. This is because I believe it requires TLS 1.2 for secure connections and OpenSSL on MacOS X used by system Python 2.7, only supports up to TLS 1.1.

You will have to use either Python from HomeBrew, or PSF version of Python 3.6. If using PSF Python 3.6, ensure you do the extra post install step to install the certificate bundle.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh, that could explain it, I knew something was outdated but not sure what. Thanks let me try this on my fedora box and will get back to you real quick.

Comment: Btw, I forgot to mention that I installed python from source, so not sure if that gives any more information.

Comment: If you install Python 2.7 from source code it will still likely use system OpenSSL library by default. You can easily check if this might be the issue by first running ``curl --tlsv1.1`` against the Kubernetes endpoint. If it fails it confirms that TLS 1.2 is required. Then in Python go ``import ssl; print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION_INFO``. If the version is 0.9.8 then it is using old OpenSSL that doesn't support TLS 1.2.

Comment: Added the output of the commands to my OP, also it seems that my machine is up to spec... weird. Could it be the kubernetes cluster hosts not being up to date?

Comment: Ahh, I should have looked more closely. Is evident that is not TLS version as the error is from Kubernetes itself.